# JQuery DataTables Search based on StartsWith Not Contains

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable

I was working on MVC3 with Jquery DataTables. There every grid consist of search function where it searches the content by matching input character (say like, using contains). But I need the result should be using StartsWith.

I need something like this,

**Grid Records**

```
1. Pipefitting Annotated instructor guide level 1 CD-ROM
2. Adobe Photoshop CS4 for photographers A professional image editors
```

If I Input character 'a', the result should come with second row (By searching starting character of the word in a string). or If I type 'g' then the result should be of first record.

I have googled a lot but I haven't find anything that matches my requirement. Please suggest me how can i do this.

**View Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CollectionTable').dataTable({
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"}).makeEditable({
            "aoColumns": [
                null, null
                ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

With datatables 1.10.9, to search for values starting with the parameters you will enter is quite simple.

I did a bit of research myself, but the datatables API has the inbuilt column filters to do what you are looking for.

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();

        $('#name').on( 'keyup', function () {

            table
                .columns( 0 ) // 0 based column
                .search( "^"+this.value, true, true, true )
                .draw();

        } );
```

table is the datatable object

and #name is the input box from which i pass the parameter.

You can define the column you are interested in, followed by passing in the regular expression query in the search against your parameter.

You can find examples for the above in the official documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29)

Comment: DataTables documentation says that the regex and smart search options may conflict with each other, so you probably don't want to enable both options at the same time.  https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Answer (score 0):

fnFilter allows you to filter the table using regular expressions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sometime later - filter...
  oTable.fnFilter( '^' + yourTerm, null, true, true, true, true);
} );
```

Full reference: http://www.datatables.net/ref